# It can make a modal popup window with just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I would be interested to know if you can make a modal pop-up window just using HTML and CSS without JQuery.

Does anyone know such a simple example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Design a popup, yes. But I don't think you'll be able to show/hide it without JS

Answer (score 3):

A modal with only HTML and CSS no jQuery or javascript

```css
body {
color: #333333;
font-family: 'Helvetica', arial;
height: 80em;
}
.wrap {
padding: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
hr {
clear: both;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
border: 0;
border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
h1 {
font-size: 30px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
p {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn {
background: #428bca;
border: #357ebd solid 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
min-width: 60px;
position: relative;
transition: color .1s ease;
/* top: 40em;*/
}
.btn:hover {
background: #357ebd;
}
.btn.btn-big {
font-size: 18px;
padding: 15px 20px;
min-width: 100px;
}
.btn-close {
color: #aaaaaa;
font-size: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 0;
}
.btn-close:hover {
color: #919191;
}
.modal:before {
content: "";
display: none;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 10;
}
.modal:target:before {
display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
transform: translate(0, 0);
top: 20%;
}
.modal-dialog {
background: #fefefe;
border: #333333 solid 1px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: -200px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: -100%;
z-index: 11;
width: 360px;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
transform: translate(0, -500%);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal-body {
padding: 20px;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modal-header {
border-bottom: #eeeeee solid 1px;
}
.modal-header h2 {
font-size: 20px;
}
.modal-footer {
border-top: #eeeeee solid 1px;
text-align: right;
}
/*ADDED TO STOP SCROLLING TO TOP*/
#close {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <h1>Modal - Pure CSS (no Javascript)</h1>
  
  <hr />

  <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a>
  
</div>
 
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
      <a href="#close" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a> <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#close" class="btn">Nice!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use the `:target` pseudo selector to show a modal.
Here's an example including some transitions as well (code combined from shehary's codepen example and http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects):

```css
body {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

a {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #a5281b;
}
body > a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.md-modal {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 630px;
 min-width: 320px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 2000;
 visibility: hidden;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.md-modal:target {
 visibility: visible;
}

.md-overlay {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 visibility: hidden;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 opacity: 0;
 background: rgba(143,27,15,0.8);
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-modal:target ~ .md-overlay {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}

/* Content styles */
.md-content {
 color: #fff;
 background: #e74c3c;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.md-content h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.4em;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2.4em;
 font-weight: 300;
 opacity: 0.8;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.md-content > div {
 padding: 15px 40px 30px;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1.15em;
}

.md-content > div p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.md-content > div ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
}

.md-content > div ul li {
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.md-content a {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* Effect */

.md-modal .md-content {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
 transform: scale(0.7);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-modal:target .md-content {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#modal">MODAL</a>

<div class="md-modal" id="modal">
 <div class="md-content">
  <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
  <div>
   <p>This is a modal window.</p>
   <a class="md-close" href="#">Close me!</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

If you don't feel comfortable using `visibility: hidden` you can use `display: none` instead. But you better remove the transitions in that case (`visibility` can be used in a transition, `display` can't).