# How to display Alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

How do I display a simple alert in javascript without the title on top of the alert - Just a blank alert with just message.

Comment: You don't use `alert()`, you display an appropriately styled `<div>` (or other HTML element(s)). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588871/it-can-make-a-modal-popup-window-with-just-html-and-css).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a JavaScript alert box title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905289/how-to-edit-a-javascript-alert-box-title)

Comment: No it is impossible to change Title you can just pass the message to `alert()`, but you can override `window.alert` to customize it as you want !!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with browser's native alert box. However you can always use JavaScript alert box.

```js
  function showAlert(){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Alert" onClick='showAlert()'>
<div id="dialog" title="" style="display: none;">
  <p>Alert box. Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: This assumes the user is wanting to use jQuery rather than just JavaScript.

Comment: ["Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)